# Requeue Ibm MQ Message

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

We are running multiple instances of a windows service that reads messages from a Topic, runs a report, then converts the results into a PDF and emails them to a user. In case of exceptions we simply log the exception and move on.

The use case we want to handle is when the service is shut down we want to preserve the jobs that are currently running so they can be reprocessed by another instance of the service or when the service is restarted.

Is there a way of requeueing a message? The hacky solution would be to just republish the message from the consuming service, but there must be another way.

When incoming messages are processed, their data is put in an internal queue structure (not a message queue) and processed in batches of parallel threads, so the IbmMq transaction stuff seems hard to implement. Is that what I should be using though?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement seems to be hard to implement if you don't get rid of the "internal queue structure (not a message queue)" if this is not based on a transaction oriented middleware. The MQ queue / topic works well for multi-threaded consumers, so it is not apparent what you gain from this intermediate step of moving the data to just another queue. If you start your transaction with consuming the message from MQ, you can have it being rolled back when something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We get parallel processing/rendering of multiple reports- as of now 10 per instance.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your use case correctly, you can use [Durable subscriptions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=subscriptions-subscription-durability):

> Durable subscriptions continue to exist when a subscribing application's connection to the queue manager is closed.

The details are explained in [DEFINE SUB (create a durable subscription)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=reference-define-sub-create-durable-subscription). Example:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL(THE.REPORTING.QUEUE) REPLACE DEFPSIST(YES)

DEFINE TOPIC(THE.REPORTING.TOPIC) REPLACE +
   TOPICSTR('/Path/To/My/Interesting/Thing') DEFPSIST(YES) DURSUB(YES)

DEFINE SUB(THE.REPORTING.SUB) REPLACE +
   TOPICOBJ(THE.REPORTING.TOPIC) DEST(THE.REPORTING.QUEUE)
```

Your service instances can consume now from `THE.REPORTING.QUEUE`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We're already using durable subscriptions and when the services start up they will pull any messages off the queue that have built up in the down time. 

But the issue were trying to solve for is how to put a message that is still being processed back on the queue when the application is shut down.

Comment: Ok, then you just simple consume them in a MQ transaction; when the service shuts down uncontrolled, the transaction gets rolled back and the message is on the queue again. Remember to define `BOTHRESH(1)` (1 or higher) and `BOQNAME(THE.REPORTING.QUEUE.BO)`.

Answer (score -2):

While I readily admit that my knowledge is shaky, from what I understood from IBM’s [sketchy, inadequate, obtuse] documentation there really is no good built in solution. With transactions the Queue Manager assumes all is well unless it receives a roll back request and when it does it rolls back to a syncpoint, so if you’re trying to roll back to one message but two other messages have completed in the meantime it will roll back all three.

We ended up coding our own solution updating the way we’re logging messages and marking them as completed in the DB. Then on both startup and shutdown we find the uncompleted messages and programmatically publish them back to the queue, limiting the DB search by machine name so if we have multiple instances of the service running they won’t duplicate message processing.